# TSQL: sum before and after today per customer

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have this table...

```
TABLE [orders] (
   [customer_ID] uniqueidentifier,
   [salary] money,
   [enter_into_force_date] date
)
```

I need to group by "customer_ID" and have the salary sum before today (enter_into_force_date <= getdate) and the salary sum after today (enter_into_force_date > getdate) - that is, I need to know per customer, what salary sum we have up till today and what salary will be in the future.

So the result should look like...

```
customer_ID                            before_today  after_today
7FBF73B0-6F18-488B-8BEA-CB1968473BBE      20,100.00    10,211.00
679329F5-D7BB-44BE-9E76-F2F02DE5FD00       1,500.10    30.100,10
```

How would I make such TSQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this query

```
select customer_id,
    sum(case when enter_into_force_date <= GETDATE() then salary else 0 end) before_today,
    sum(case when enter_into_force_date <= GETDATE() then 0 else salary end) after_today
from orders
group by customer_id
```

Comment: Perfect .. thanks a lot - I've learned something new today ... thanks. :)

Comment: +1 . . . I want to point that that using the same condition and swapping the `then` and `else` clauses ensures that `NULL`s get counted as well.